“This basically is my lifestyle.” or “This is basically my lifestyle.”
Which one is correct?


This basically is my lifestyle.

This is basically my lifestyle.




basically is a speech-act adjunct. It is the speaker commenting, in the utterance, on the utterance. Such adjuncts can appear in the clause in various places.
Basically, this is my lifestyle.
This, basically, is my lifestyle.
This is basically my lifestyle.
This is my lifestyle, basically.

What extra information does 'This, basically, is my lifestyle' convey that 'This is my lifestyle' does not? Many people find 'basically' a terribly overused word.

@MichaelHarvey Depends on the context.  Is the speaker is showing someone their cramped one-room apartment in NYC, or their golden toilet?

The default sequence in English is the adverb (basically, here) comes immediately after the verb (is, here).
Many adverbs, particularly those that are common in casual spoken contexts, such as basically, really, often, simply,... can occur before OR after the verb.
But as a general principle, since after the verb is the default, placing them before the verb is likely to be at least slightly "marked" (will be noticed as "not the default choice" by most native speakers).
Native speakers assume other native speakers are aware of the default, so if we hear a "marked" form, we assume the speaker has done this deliberately. If there's no other obvious reason for the "non-default" choice, we assume it's intended to convey emphasis. It really isn't complicated - which phrasing is more emphatic than It isn't really complicated.
